# How do joins compare with other queries in SQL?

Tags: sql, join, processing-efficiency

Is there any reason to say that:

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, Address 
FROM EMPLOYEE, DEPARTMENT
WHERE Dname='Research' AND Dnumber=Dno;
```

is better/worse than using:

```
SELECT Fname, Lname, Address
FROM (EMPLOYEE JOIN DEPARTMENT ON Dno=Dnumber)
WHERE Dname='Research';
```

The second is probably more readable, but is there any difference in terms of efficiency?

Comment: See this https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/78225/using-join-keyword-or-not

Comment: the `comma` join is old school.. best practice is define it explicitly...who knows when the old one will be deprecated

Comment: The explicit syntax is preferred by most people, but both are valid Standard SQL syntax (SQL 89/SQL 92). Tthere should be no difference performance wise.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are doing a cross join which creates a cartesian product first and filters on the where clause by comparing each attribute(Dnumber and Dno in your case) with the other.

However in the second query, unless you specify the type of join, you do an inner join by default. This creates the result based on the ON  condition. This results in the query engine (which may vary from vendors and flavours), using the ON condition to perform the intersection of the two tables.

Cheers!